# determine if "a" element inside li has a CSS class with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, nav

I want to do some actions depending on **a** element inside a **li element** and a submenu class in **li element**.
If the element has 2 classess `current submenu` i want to do some action when **$(".menu").mouseenter** event occurs. If the li element does not have this do something else....

```
    <nav id="id"> 
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">index</a></li>
        <li><a href="serviceios.html" class="current submenu">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="clients.html" >Clients</a></li>
        <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html" >Contact</a></li>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#" class="documents" data-icon="&#xe000">1</a></li>

            <li><a href="#" class="messages" data-icon="&#xe001">2</a></li>

            <li><a href="#" class="signout" data-icon="&#xe002">3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I have:

```
$(".menu").mouseenter(
    function() {
        $(".menu").toggleClass('hover');
        $(".submenu").css("-webkit-border-radius", "8px 8px 0 0");
        $(".submenu").css("-moz-border-radius", "8px 8px 0 0");
        $(".submenu").css("border-radius", "8px 8px 0 0");
        if( $('li').hasClass('current submenu') )
            /*...*/
        else
            $(".submenu").toggleClass('current');
    }
);
```

what to do?

Comment: Which `li` element do you need to check? Do you need any data from that element?

Comment: None of your li's have any classes.  They are all in the anchor tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting `class` to the `a` element inside the `li`, so `a` will have the class.

Use this. This will select the `a` with class `submenu current` inside an `li`.

```
if( $('li a.submenu').hasClass('current') ) {
    console.log("Got an li");
    /* Do stuff here */
} else {
    $(".submenu").toggleClass('current');
}
```

If you are sure there is only one element with `submenu` class at a time, then you can also do:

```
if( $('.submenu').hasClass('current') ) {
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jFen9/)

Answer (score 3):

This jQuery object:

```
$("li a.current.submenu")
```

will select all tags with both those classes on it and only those tags.  You can use that jQuery object to confine any operation to only those tags.

Or, if you want to iterate through all `li a.submenu` items and do one thing if the current class is there and another if not, you can do this:

```
$("li a.submenu").each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("current")) {
        // do something here when current class is present
    } else {
        // do something here when current class is not present
    }
});
```